# Update git submodules

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

On trying to update git submodule, I see the following error:

```
Submodule 'paa' (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/paa.git) registered for path 'paa'
Cloning into 'D:/a/1/s/paa'...
git: 'credential-manager-core' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/microsoftgraph/paa.git' into submodule path 'D:/a/1/s/paa' failed
Failed to clone 'paa'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into 'D:/a/1/s/paa'...
git: 'credential-manager-core' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/microsoftgraph/paa.git' into submodule path 'D:/a/1/s/paa' failed
Failed to clone 'paa' a second time, aborting
##[error]Git submodule update failed with exit code: 1
```

I referenced [Fatal Error when updating submodule using GIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197089/fatal-error-when-updating-submodule-using-git) stack overflow post and .gitmodules already has the following content:

```
[submodule "paa"]
    path = paa
    url = https://github.com/microsoftgraph/paa.git
```

UPDATE:

Based on below answer I added a PATH as follows:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core
```

I still see the same error. I tried updating the content in .gitmodules to the following:

```
[submodule "paa"]
    path = paa
    url = https://<username>:<password>@github.com/microsoftgraph/paa.git
```

I see this error:

```
Submodule 'paa' (https://<username>:<password>@github.com/microsoftgraph/paa.git) registered for path 'paa'
Cloning into 'D:/a/1/s/paa'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://<username>:<password>@github.com/microsoftgraph/paa.git/': Could not resolve host: <username>:<password>@github.com
fatal: clone of 'https://<username>:<password>@github.com/microsoftgraph/paa.git' into submodule path 'D:/a/1/s/paa' failed
```

Comment: Evidence of what you actually did to get this.  "credential-manager-core" is a third-party add-on that stock Git doesn't use, and you didn't show what you did use.

Comment: Just to check, can you go into your repo and type `git config -l`: do you see any setting with `insteadOf` in it?

Comment: I see this: url.git@github.com:.insteadof=https://github.com/, url.https://github.com:.insteadof=git@github.com/

Answer (score 2):

For all my recent (2.29) Windows Git installations, I had to add `%GH%\mingw64\libexec\git-core` to my `PATH` (`GH` is the path where Git is installed).
See [`VonC/setupsenv` commit f1a1dcd](https://github.com/VonC/setupsenv/commit/f1a1dcdcb0994252b95ec80dcf8e71c97c3cfb9b) as an example:

```
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\cmd;%GH%\usr\bin;
set PATH=%GH%\mingw64\bin;%GH%\mingw64\libexec\git-core;%PATH%
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That way, the [GCM (Microsoft Git-Credential-Manager-Core](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/) becomes available and the error message is no more.

Comment: Thank you! Question - I have Git installed in C:\Program Files. I added paths as you suggested (please see my updated question) and I still see same error. What am I missing?

Comment: @user989988 What does return the command `where git-credential-manager-core`. And what version of Git for Windows are you using?

Comment: It returns nothing when I run the command where git-credential-manager-core. PS C:\Users\alias> where git-credential-manager-core
PS C:\Users\alias> Git version is git version 2.29.2.windows.1

Comment: @user989988 Exactly: the PATH has not been set properly. Try and set it globally in your User environment variables, then open a new CMD/Powershell session, and try again.

Comment: Makes sense - the procedure I did to set PATH is open Control Panel\System and Security\System-> Advanced system settings -> Environment variables -> Path -> Edit -> add all the paths. Could you please confirm if that's the right way? On running git config --list --show-origin, I see credential.helper=wincred

Comment: @user989988 Yes, and you need to change: `git config --global credential.helper manager-core`. Assuling Git 2.29 (preferably 2.29.2)

Comment: I ran the command git config --global credential.helper manager-core I still see the same error

Comment: @user989988 That is because you are not running it in a CMD where the PATH is correctly set and where the command `where git-credential-manager-core` does return something.

Comment: You are right - on running in CMD, I see this: C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-credential-manager-core.exe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224055/discussion-between-vonc-and-user989988).